# tcl expr not rounding like i expect

Tags: tcl, rounding, expr

Im new to tcl and i have these numbers:

`set a 565056236086`
`set b 488193341805`

the output of  `$a / $b` is 1,157443552992375

When i use the following code

`set num [expr {double(round(100*$a / $b))/100}]`

the output is: 1,15

but i want 1.16 how can i round it like that?

Comment: Are you going to be doing further calculations with the value, or is this for display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make either `a` or `b` a double *before* doing the operations. Also, `round` returns an integer, so you either need to convert it to double too, or divide by a double:

```
set num [expr {round(100*double($a) / $b)/100.0}]
# 1.16
```

Or if you specifically need to round up, then, you can use [`ceil`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/mathfunc.htm#M29) (since this one returns a double, you don't need to divide by a double):

```
set num [expr {ceil(100*double($a) / $b)/100}]
# 1.16
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure you are doing floating point division by making sure either, or both values are a double (e.g. using double($a) and/or double($b)). Then rounding to a certain number of decimal digits is most easily done with format:

```
format %.2f [expr {double($a) / $b}]
```